# how to concatenate inside data of two files

Tags: linux, bash

For eg two files name abc.txt & def.txt  have below data

abc.txt

```
apple
carrot
```

def.txt

```
fruit
Vegetable
```

SO i want o/p like below:

```
apple fruit
carrot Vegetable
```

Comment: That would be a job for the `paste` command - see `man paste`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
paste -d' ' abc.txt def.txt > output.txt
```

also, related question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806874/how-to-merge-two-files-line-by-line-in-bash